# How is gbm package different from caret with gbm method?

Tags: r, caret, boosting

I have a gbm problem and I am using the gbm package in R for it. But in most forums I see people using caret package for gbm. Is there any advantage of using caret instead of gbm package? If so, what sort of advantages do we have, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: http://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v028i05 `caret` can be seen (among other relevant advantages, to be sure) as a "wrapper" for packages like `gbm`, so in terms of statistical results they should produce identical results (given identical tuning parameters, of course). So ease of use may favor `caret`, especially if you aim to use other ML techniques at the same time.